# Is a Microsoft Exchange 2003 Front-End Server Required to be a DNS Server?

Tags: exchange-2003

I adopted a junk environment, and I'm trying to stabilize it before I can migrate it to something better.  My Exchange environment consists of

- (1) front-end server
- (1) smart-host behind the firewall
- (5) back-end servers

These servers are on Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2.

For some reason, the front-end server has a DNS server role on it.  This is causing problems with Active-Sync since the DNS server is randomly taking ports, and sometimes takes the Active-Sync port. I already have an Active Directory server with the DNS role. Is a Microsoft Exchange 2003 Front-End Server required to be a DNS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, definitely not.

*Some more characters to fill the answer requirement*